# Python Regex that matches a certain string with or without inclusion of a character?

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm trying to match strings with exactly 1-4 digits, with or without the inclusion of 'x'at the beginning of the match after an optional separator. Here is the separator just in case: (this part is fine)

```
[ .\-]*
```

so for example, within

```
blahblah-123 hahaha
sdsshgs.x7
3343434 093798
```

these will be matched:

```
123
x7
```

I've managed to match numbers with 1-4 digits,with this:

```
(\b\d{1,4}\b)?
```

At the same time, I'd like to be able to match 1-4 digit strings with an 'x' at the beginning, so I have this.

```
(\bx\d{1,4}\b)?
```

Now the only issue is putting them together into one regex. Maybe a '|' would be useful for that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `?` means 0 or 1 of the preceding character `"x?"` means 0 or 1 x characters.

Comment: Try `[ -\.](x?\d{1,4})\b`.

Comment: @recursive Yes, I understand that somewhat, the code is supposed to be alright with things if the match isn't found. As of now there's no problem with it, I think. EDIT: oh so that's where I was supposed to use it. Thanks!

Comment: @approxiblue Yes, this does the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @approxiblue Actually, it doesn't match exactly 1-4 digits. It just cuts them down if they exceed 4. I've found a solution though there probably is something much shorter out there. (\bx\d{1,4}\b|\b\d{1,4}\b)?

Comment: @imgoingmad There's the `\b` at the end, meaning it won't match if the number has more digits / we run into white space. Same as your version.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[ -\.](x?\d{1,4})\b`. – approxiblue